# Converting an es6 arrow function to es5 manually?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, arrow-functions

How do we convert the arrow function below to es5 manually?

```
e => varName = e.target.value
```

My attempt:

```
function(e) {
 varName = e.target.value
 return varName
}
```

Am I right?

What about this below?

```
varName = function(e) {
 return e.target.value
}
```

Comment: Your first attempt is correct.

Comment: The closest would be `return varName = e.target.value;` but at the end of the day the difference is negligible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of them are extremely similar and perform *nearly* the same task, however the ES6 function implicitly creates a global variable named `varName` and assigns it a value, and neither of the ES5 functions do that. This one is pretty much exactly the same:

```
function(e) {
  return varName = e.target.value;
}
```

Or:

```
function(e) {
  varName = e.target.value;
  return varName;
}
```

Comment: The first ES5 one does do that.